# Access to different object properties through an interface? C#

Tags: c#, interface, factory

I am programming a dll with a factory pattern on C#. The factory receive an enum and return an interface. Depending on the received enum it create different objects and return it encapsulated in the interface. Any class inside the factory implements the interface and its access modifier is internal, except the own interface which is public.

The problem is when i call the dll from the main project. Each object created inside the factory has different properties and do not why i can not access or modify those properties from the main. Some help?

this is the Factory call from the main.

`IConfigurator config = ConfigFactory.Instance.CreateConfigurator(Model.First);`

This is how the factory works (inside the dll):

```
public IConfigurator CreateConfigurator(Model model)
    {
        switch (model)
        {
            case Model.First:
                return (First)new First(model);

            case Model.Second:
                return (Second)new Second(model);

            case Model.Third:
                return (Third)new Third(model);

        }

    }
```

First, Second and Third has different properties and i am not able to modify it from the interface object received

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by you can't modify the properties? You need to share your code for us to be able to provide proper solution.

Comment: The whole point of using an interface is that you have objects that conform to the interface and code that treats them equally. It doesn't sound like that's the case for you.

Comment: Excuse me, i have already edit the question with the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you're returning an interface, therefore only the properties that are part of the interface are available until you cast the object to its concrete type.

For example:

```
public class A : INameable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class B : INameable
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public Interface INameable
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}

public Enum Selector
{
    A,
    B
}
```

So if I use a method as follows

```
public INameable GetINameable(Selector selector)
{
   if (selector.Equals(Selctor.A))
       return new A { Name = "Name A", Age = 10 };
   if (selector.Equals(Selector.B))
       return new B { Name = "Name B", Description = "New Instance of B"};
}
```

I will get an instance of `INameable` returned and will only be able to access the `Name` property as defined in the interface.

However if I need to access the other properties then I need to cast the returned object to its concrete type as follows:

```
// This will be an instance of INameable
var obj = GetINameable(Selector.A);

// Now cast as an instance of A
var castObj = obj as A;

// We can now access the Age property
var age = castObj.Age;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have tried it, but the problem what i have now is the different classes does not have the same attributes, so if i implement the properties in the interface, each class must implement the properties independently if it class has this attribute or not.

Comment: Only put properties in the interface that are required. When you get back an instance of the interface from the method call, if you need to access the concrete type's other properties then cast it as the concrete type to do so.

Comment: Ok, but can i do it from the main taking into account the classes to cast are internal? Or i should modify it to public?

Comment: I assume you mean the `Main()` method right? If they're in the same assembly it won't be a problem. If not then it will need to know about the classes yes.

Comment: Yes, is the Main(). But are not in the same workspace are 2 different projects. I have modified the Quesition above, there you can see a piece of code. The main call to the factory is in one project and the factory is in other project.

Answer (score 0):

The method can have only one return type.
Instead of chossing result by enum, create different factory method / factory class for every item.

Sample:

```
// instead of this
public enum FactoryEnum {
   VariantA,
   VariantB,
   VariantC
}
object Create(FactoryEnum item);

// do this
IMyInterfaceA CreateA();
IMyInterfaceB CreateB();
IMyInterfaceC CreateC();
```